# No output when compiling kotlin-js IR using kotlinc cli

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlinc

I'm trying to compile a kotlin file `test.kt` using `kotlinc-js`:

```kt
fun main() {
    println("Hello world!")
    val a = add(7, 22)
    println("Added to get $a")
}

fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    val z = x + y
    println(z)
    println("Hello $y")
    return z
}
```

I downloaded the kotlinc zip file from github, worked through some errors, and eventually arrived here:

```
kotlinc/bin/kotlinc-js -Xir-produce-js -libraries ".\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib-js.jar" -ir-output-dir build -ir-output-name test.js test.kt
```

This seems to be successful with this output:

```
info: produce executable: build
info: cache directory: null
info: executable production duration: 3740ms
```

It creates the build directory, but there are no files within it. I can't figure out what to do from here.

I've tried adding more libraries like so:

```
kotlinc/bin/kotlinc-js -Xir-produce-js -libraries ".\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib-js.jar;.\kotlinc\lib\kotlin-stdlib.jar" -ir-output-dir build -ir-output-name test.js test.kt
```

But any library after the first one gives the following error:

```
error: source entry is not a Kotlin file
```

I found [a YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49894) which detailed similar problems to those I was having initially (which is how I came up with the command I am using right now), but I don't know how to continue from here.

I am using [Kotlin 1.8.22](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.8.22) in PowerShell 7.3.4 on Windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and tested many flags combinations until I discovered that it works with **absolute path for `-ir-output-dir` flag**. I wonder where the output go when this path is relative.